# How do I center the value of the textfield (flutter)

Tags: flutter, textfield, center

How do I center the value of the textfield (flutter). So that it always stays in the center no matter how big the word is? And also how do i remove the underline bar?

```
new Container(

        alignment: Alignment(0.00 , 0.50),

       child: new TextField(                                 
    style: new TextStyle(
      fontSize: 40.0,
      height: 2.0,
      color: Colors.white                  
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Anton, have you tried `textAlign: TextAlign.center`to center the text and decoration below to remove underline bar?

```
TextField(
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  style: new TextStyle(
    fontSize: 22.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
  decoration: new InputDecoration.collapsed(
    hintText: "Name",
  )
)
```

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Border can be removed by using inputBorder.none. TextAlign.center is used to set the text center but  you have to use the inputDecoration.collapsed instead of inputDecoration.

```
TextFormField(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(
                   hintText: "Enter Your Name",
                      border: InputBorder.none
                  )
                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [decoration](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration-class.html) and the textAlign properties, try the next code:

`TextField(
    ....

    decoration: InputDecoration(
        enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
        ),
        focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
        ),
    ),
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
);`